# How to determine if a given function is a valid cdf, pmf, or pdf?

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions

Studying for a statistics exam. I have come across this problem:

[image]

and it presents to me some important and extremely basic questions (I have a LONG way to go before I'm prepared for this exam).

1. Can these functions be both cdfs and pdfs/pmfs? Or are they one or the other? Is this a yes/no or a cdf/pdf/pmf question?
2. What criteria do we use to evaluate if they are valid cdfs or pdfs/pmfs?
3. A friend iterated I should integrate across the range of the "functiony" bit of the functions (the terms with x) and if the result is 1, that the functions are valid. But valid what?

Comment: This should get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Answer (score 2):

I think giving an answer in terms of probability axioms is not quite at the level of the OP's actual question.

Typically, we denote a density using lowercase $f$, and a cumulative distribution as uppercase $F$.  A PDF must satisfy two basic criteria:  (1) it must be nonnegative everywhere, and (2) it must integrate to $1$ over its support (the support is the set of $x$-values where the density is positive).  A CDF must satisfy three criteria:  (1) $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = 0$, (2) $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} F(x) = 1$, and (3) it must be nondecreasing.

A quick sketch of the various functions will reveal if some of these conditions are violated.  For (a) you need to test if $4x^4-3x^2$ is an increasing function on $[0,1]$--you would do this by calculating the derivative and seeing if it is nonnegative; for (b) you need to do the same (but it should be obvious that it is not); for (c) and (d), integrate the functions over their respective supports $[0,2]$ and $[0,1]$, and check that both functions are nonnegative in those intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Probability Mass functions $p_{x}(x)$or Probability Density functions $f_x(x)$ have to satisfy the 3 Probability axioms:
1. $p_x(x)\geq0$
2. $\sum_{\forall x \in \Omega} p_x(x) = 1$, where $\Omega$ is the sample space
3. Any countable sequence of disjoint events $E_1,E_2\dotsb$ satisfy $P(E_1 \bigcup E_2 \bigcup \dots )=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(E_i)$

The same apply for $f_x(x)$. This is not a Yes/No question and you need to verify that the above conditions are satisfied.